# Sql and Php - ordering a list

Tags: php, sql

I have a list of clients contacts that currently gets pulled from a table and each client contact has an id of a client.

In another dropdown I have a list of clients.

what I would like to be able to do is once the project is chosen is to modify the client contact list to show the client contacts with that id at the top of the list and every other contact name below

the below sql gets the client contacts

```
$clients = db()->select("SELECT DISTINCT
rjcn.client_name , jtp.project, rjcn.id
from rejuvenate_jobs_client_names AS rjcn
LEFT JOIN jt_projects AS jtp
ON jtp.id = rjcn.client_id");
```

Comment: What have you done so far? what is your query looking like..?done

Comment: added sql to the question

Comment: And you want the result with the highest ID to be at the top..?done

Comment: managed to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

```
$clients = db()->select("
    SELECT DISTINCT rjcn.client_name , jtp.project, rjcn.id, rjcn.client_id
    FROM rejuvenate_jobs_client_names AS rjcn
    LEFT JOIN jt_projects AS jtp
    ON jtp.id = rjcn.client_id
    ORDER BY clientid = " . id of selected project in here . " desc , rjcn.id desc");
```